# if $gcd(a,b)=gcd(a,b,c)$ then I need to prove that $ax+by=c$ has solution in $\mathbb Z$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

if $gcd(a,b)=gcd(a,b,c)$ then I need to prove that $ax+by=c$ has solution in $\mathbb Z$ that is: $gcd(a,b)|c$

but how can I prove it with the given hypothesis?

Comment: Can you prove that if $\operatorname{gcd}(k,c)=k$ then $k\mid c$? Now set $k=\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)$.

Answer (score 3):

You're pretty much there. $d = (a,b) = (a,b,c)$. So in particular, $d \mid c$.

It seems you already know that we can write $ax'+by'=d$ For $x', y' \in \mathbb Z$, and then multiplying by a suitable integer will give you the solution you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

First divide $a,b,c$ by $\gcd(a,b)$ so that we can assume that $a,b$ (and therefore $a,b,c$) are relatively prime.

Apply now Euclid's algorithm to $a,b$. This will give you equations:

$a=bq_1+r_1$, $b=q_2r_1+r_2$, ..., $r_n=q_{n+1}r_{n-1}+r_{n+1}$, where $r_{n+1}=1$ is the $\gcd(a,b)$.

Substituting backwards these equations we get $ax+by=1$. Multiply the whole equation by $c$ to get $a(cx)+b(cy)=c$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $ $ Recall $ \ d = \gcd(a,b,c)\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}d\mid a,b,\color{#c00}c,\ $ i.e. the $\rm\,g\color{#0a0}{cd}$ is a $\rm\color{#0a0}{c}ommon\ \color{#0a0}{d}ivisor$ of its arguments.

In your case $ \ d = \gcd(a,b)\,$ thus $\, \color{#c00}{d}\mid \color{#c00}c\, $ becomes $\,\gcd(a,b)\mid c,\,$ as desired

Comment: thanks a lot!: for the inverse: if $ax+by=c$ has solution in $\mathbb Z$ then $gcd(a,b)=gcd(a,b,c)$ can I do it like this?: Let $d=(a,b)$ by hypothesis $d|c$ so does this imply that $d=(d,c)=(a,b,c)$?

Comment: @use $\ $ Yes $\ d = \gcd(d,c)\, \color{#c00}{\Leftarrow}\!\!\Rightarrow\, d\mid c.\ $  You can do  $\,(\color{#c00}\Leftarrow)\,$ by the Euclidean algorithm. viz.
 $${\gcd(d,c)\, =\, \gcd(d,\!\! \underbrace{c\ {\rm mod}\ d}_{\large\ =\, 0\ 
\,{\rm by}\,\ d\mid c}\!\!) \,=\, \gcd(d,0) = d}\qquad\qquad\qquad$$

Answer (score 0):

let $g = gcd(a,b) = gcd(a,b,c)$, $c=d*g$

it exists $u,v$ such as $a*u+b*v=g$, $a*u*d+b*v*d=g*d=c$

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**
**I.**
$\gcd(n,m)=n\iff n\mid m.$
**II.**
$\gcd(a,b,c)=\gcd(\gcd(a,b),c).$

Hope this helps.